# Ajax remoteFunction not calling action

Tags: ajax, grails

I'm currently trying to make a dynamic drop down menu in Grails and I have an Ajax statement that is supposed to retrieve the value from the option clicked and populate the second drop down menu with the items respective to the first option the user clicked. Here is my statement and call in my gsp file:

```
<div class="fieldcontain">
    <g:select name="termSelection" from="${Term.list()}" values="${params.id}" optionKey="id" optionValue="semester" noSelection="['':'----Term----']"
                 onchange="${remoteFunction (controller: 'term', action: 'findWeeksForSemester', params: '\'term.id=\' + this.value', update: 'weekSelection')}"/>

</div>
<br>
<td id="weekSelection">
    <select>
        <option>----Week----</option>
        <g:select name="week.id" from="${Week.list()}" optionValue="week" optionKey="id"/>
    </select>
</td>
```

The function the action is calling is this:

```
def findWeeksForSemester = {
    println("Testing for action event")
    println(params)
    def term = Term.get(params.term.id)
    render(template: 'weekSelection', model:  [week: term.week])
}
```

When debugging through it I found that it doesn't even call the action function. Is there any way to fix this or do I need to go about it in a different way?

Comment: Show the resulting rendered html.

Comment: The resulting html is the same as the loaded html page because the action does not load the method so it does not render another page.

Comment: I believe James is asking what is rendered for your select tag, before you even try to make a call to the action, confirm your calling code (e.g. onchange="...") is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `javascript` library (which supports AJAX) in the `head` of the GSP in order to make the `remoteFunction` work. Something like below if you wan to extend the default `sitemesh layout` from Grails

```
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
    <title>Term</title>
    <g:javascript library="jquery"/>
</head>
```

I was able to make your use case work (bootstrapped domain and did more). If required I can send it over. Refer [Ajax Section](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/single.html#ajax) in Grails docs for details.